# zip multiple directories in Powershell using .NET classes, instead of compress-archive

Tags: powershell, zip, system.io.compression

I am trying to use .NET classes instead of native `compress-archive` to zip multiple directories (each containing sub-directories and files), as `compress-archive` is giving me occasional `OutOfMemory` Exception.

Some articles tell me .NET classes, makes for a more optimal approach.

My tools directory `$toolsDir = 'C:\Users\Public\LocalTools'` has more than one directory that need to be zipped (please note everything is a directory, not file) - whichever directory matches the regex pattern as in the code.

Below is my code:

```
$cmpname = $env:computername
$now = $(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddmmhhss)
$pattern = '^(19|[2-9][0-9])\d{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])T((?:[01]\d|2[0-3])\;[0-5]\d\;[0-5]\d)\.(\d{3}Z)\-' + [ regex ]::Escape($cmpname)
$toolsDir = 'C:\Users\Public\LocalTools'
$destPathZip = "C:\Users\Public\ToolsOutput.zip"

 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$CompressionLevel = [ System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel ]::Optimal
$IncludeBaseDirectory = $false
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destPathZip , [ System.IO.FileMode ]::OpenOrCreate)
$zip = New-Object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream , 'update')

 
$res = Get-ChildItem "${toolsDir}" | Where-Object {$_ .Name -match "${pattern}"}

if ($res -ne $null) {
    foreach ($dir in $res) {
       $source = "${toolsDir}\${dir}"
       [ System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions ]::CreateEntryFromFile($destPathZip , $source , (Split-Path $source -Leaf), $CompressionLevel)

    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "Nothing to Archive!"

}
```

Above code gives me this error:
[image: error1]

[image]

When I researched about `[ System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions ]::CreateEntryFromFile` , it is used to add `files` to a zip file already created. Is this the reason I am getting the error that I get ?

I also tried  `[ System.IO.Compression.ZipFile ]::CreateFromDirectory($source , $destPathZip , $CompressionLevel, $IncludeBaseDirectory)` instead of  `[ System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions ]::CreateEntryFromFile($destPathZip , $source , (Split-Path $source -Leaf), $CompressionLevel)`

That gives me `"The file 'C:\Users\Public\ToolsOutput.zip' already exists` error.

How to change the code, in order to add multiple directories in the zip file.

Comment: The first argument to `CreateEntryFromFile` should be a target `ZipArchive` object, so pass `$zip` in place of `$destPathZip`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. After making the change, the error is gone. But its creating blank zip file `ToolsOutput.zip`. It doesn't actually archive anything

Comment: You need to flush both streams before the data is saved to file, I'll write up an answer in a second

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks that would help. I also did another test. It says `Access to the path 'C:\Users\Public\LocalTools\dirToarchive' is denied`. The reason is probably because of the `flush` not happening. Will wait for your answer.

Comment: As aside, I don't know why you're doing things like this where you leave spaces and the use of double-quotes `" ${toolsDir} \ ${dir} "`, this will be literal spaces in your path string. Same thing for the pattern variable

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for the comment . That might have been an error while copying the code. Edited the question. That is not in my original code.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Edited the code in question. Can you help on the original question please.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems with your code currently:

1. First argument passed to `CreateEntryFromFile()` must be a `ZipArchive` object in which to add the new entry - in your case you'll want to pass the `$zip` which you've already created for this purpose.
2. `CreateEntryFromFile` only creates 1 entry for 1 file per call - to recreate a whole directory substructure you need to calculate the correct entry path for each file, eg. `subdirectory/subsubdirectory/file.exe`
3. You need to properly dispose of both the `ZipArchive` *and* the underlying file stream instances in order for the data to be persisted on disk. For this, you'll need a `try`/`finally` statement.

Additionally, there's no need to create the file if there are no files to archive :)

```
$cmpname = $env:computername
$pattern = '^(19|[2-9][0-9])\d{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])T((?:[01]\d|2[0-3])\;[0-5]\d\;[0-5]\d)\.(\d{3}Z)\-' + [regex]::Escape($cmpname)
$toolsDir = 'C:\Users\Public\LocalTools'
$destPathZip = "C:\Users\Public\ToolsOutput.zip"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$CompressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal

$res = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $toolsDir | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $pattern }

if ($res) {
  try {
    # Create file + zip archive instances
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destPathZip, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
    $zip = New-Object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update)

    # Discover all files to archive
    foreach ($file in $res |Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse) {
      $source = $dir.FullName

      # calculate correct relative path to the archive entry
      $relativeFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($toolsDir, $source)
      $entryName = $relativeFilePath.Replace('\', '/')

      # Make sure the first argument to CreateEntryFromFile is the ZipArchive object
      [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $source, $entryName, $CompressionLevel)
    }
  }
  finally {
    # Clean up in reverse order
    $zip, $stream | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IDisposable] } | ForEach-Object Dispose
  }
}
else {
  Write-Host "Nothing to Archive!"
}
```

Calling `Dispose()` on `$zip` will cause it to flush any un-written modifications to the underlying file stream and free any additional file handles it might have acquired, whereas calling `Dispose()` on the underlying file stream flushes those changes to the disk and closes the file handle.

Comment: It actually gives me this error: `Exception calling "CreateEntryFromFile" with "4" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\Public\LocalTools\dirToArchive' is denied` - But I know the account from which the script is run does have access to these directories. In fact `compress-archive` is able to archive the same directories, but is taking way too much memory, that is why I'm trying to move to .NET classes.

Comment: @dig_123 that makes sense - `CreateEntryFromFile()` creates entries _from files_, not entire directories :)

Comment: My question already mentions that I need to add directories to the zip file, not files, that is my requirement. Everything under `$toolsDir = 'C:\Users\Public\LocalTools'` that matches REGEX pattern in my code is ideally a directory

Comment: Please read my question, I have also mentioned that I tried using `createfromdirectory`

Comment: @dig_123 I completely missed that part, I've updated the answer :)